# WordPress theme demo shows sub-menu but not theme installation

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I was wondering if this community could help isolate and solve an issue for me. When you look at this theme demo http://themetastic.themepunch.com/, you can see drop-down submenu on the main navigation (i.e. Home > Home Example 1, Home Example 2 etc.).

However, when I install the theme, the drop-down submenu does not display. It is there in the code, but doesn't display.

Here's what I've done, with no fix:

- updated the latest theme
- switched from the child theme to the Themetastic theme
- updated all plugins and WordPress
- disabled and re-enabled all plugins
- installed a clean version of WordPress and installed only the
  Themetastic theme (http://wp-base.saveda.com/ with the menu Sample Page > Another Sample Page)
  ...nothing, no fix

If I switch to another theme, such as twentytwenty, the sub-menu appears. So it's there.

When I look more closely at the code on the theme's demo vs what I have on my site, there is an element style on the demo that appears to be turning the visibility on and off for the submenu that doesn't exist when I install the theme.

For example, the theme demo has:

`<ul class="sub-menu" style="top: 102px; visibility: visible; left: 0px; width: 177px; display: none;">`

which then toggles to this when the top menu item is hovered over:

`<ul class="sub-menu" style="top: 102px; visibility: visible; left: 0px; width: 177px; display: block;">`

While on my installed version of the theme, the submenu code is:
`<ul class="sub-menu">`
that's it, no change on hover

I haven't been able to find a theme option that addresses menu or submenus. I can't see any way to apply an element style to the menu via custom CSS. Is it JS? Their support is giving me the run around by asking me basic questions that I've already answered with 24 hours between every response.... and we're supposed to have gone live yesterday, literally. I just need to find a fix since we've build and customized two sites on this theme.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Not solution, but just direction:

Line 275 of ...wp-content/themes/themetastic/js/screen.js.

```
jQuery('.team').waitForImages(function() {
```

http://wp-base.saveda.com/ says that there is no waitForImages function.
But for http://themetastic.themepunch.com/ everything is good.

Also you can see errors in browser console (F12 for Chrome). This error prevents JS functionality to add needed classes for dropdown menu.

Comment: Thank you, this is getting me on track at least. I'm seeing a `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).waitForImages is not a function` So perhaps I need to track down where the waitForImages function is declared or defined and make sure that is included? Or comment it out?

Comment: I think you should track for element with 'team' class before. Probably you have not any of them. Also you can just comment this strings and see what will happen. Also probably you can write to support that on clean server with clean WP with their theme you have error in browser console and send this error strings to them.

Comment: Thanks Dzenly, I did the clean install and a long ticket thread to support with this information and more... no response. Very disappointing.